# action does not modify state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to add user metadata to my store when mounting a screen. However, when I send the action to the reducer, the store is not modified.

I would expect props after sending the action to be as follows:

```
{addUserMetaData: ƒ addUserMetaData(user_object),
 user: {firestore_doc: {name: "Joe"}}
}
```

What am i missing here?

To reproduce, `react-native-init mwe` then add the following code. I've added an image of the app logs below.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Screen from './src/screen';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const userReducer = function userReducer(state = {}, action) {
  console.log('action', action);
  switch (action.type) {

    case "ADD_USER_METADATA":
      return { ...state, firestore_doc: action.payload };

    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};
const store = createStore(userReducer);


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View>
            <Screen />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
};
```

**src/screen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const addUserMetaData = (user) => ({
    type: "ADD_USER_METADATA",
    payload: user
})

class Screen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const user = { name: "Joe" };
        console.log('props', this.props);
        this.props.dispatch(addUserMetaData(user));
        console.log('props after action', this.props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Welcome to react native</Text>
            </View>
          )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { user: state };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Screen);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what happens in the example you've given, but typically you define the dispatch action with `mapDispatchToProps`, as pass that into the connect function

Comment: I had that in my original MWE but removed it to make it shorter. excluding mapDispatchToProps just results in a default dispatch method being mapped to props. see https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#why-don-t-i-have-thispropsdispatch-available-in-my-connected-component

Comment: I think you'll find that the state is updating, even though it appears not to be when you log `props` directly after your dispatch. What happens if you render the props? 
`<Text>{ JSON.stringify(this.props.user) }</Text>`

Comment: You can try modify the `{ user: state.firestore_doc }` of `mapStateToProps` 's `return`

Comment: Rendering the props just shows an empty user object.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed https://snack.expo.io/@janithar/c3RhY2

Lines I changed

```
 return { ...state, firestore_doc: action.payload };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please added state.firestore_doc instead of state because in reducer action.payload assign the data in firestore_doc state so you are not getting data from state.user

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { user: state.firestore_doc };
};
```